# Spring boot service with spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.4 deployed in Tomcat is registering wrong URL in Eureka Registry

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have used spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client in my spring-boot based REST services.

The Eureka registry server is packaged as jar with embedded tomcat and running well.

**Some of the REST services are hosted inside an external tomcat server**. They each have their own context paths.

These REST services are able to connect and register to the eureka registry,
but they are registering a wrong URL.

I was able to get them to register the correct port by setting `server.port` application property in all of them to be the tomcat port, but the **context path is not getting registered correctly**.
What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Eureka doesn't register a context path

Comment: Right @spencergibb . Is there any way to solve that? 
May be I can configure some bean to customize the logic for composing the service base URL being submitted to Eureka registry?
Or, Is there any underlying technical barrier in tomcat that prevents the Java code from finding out the context path under which it is hosted?

Comment: The main challenge here is that the deployment in Dev has to use external tomcat, but will be using boot-jar in test and production environments.

Comment: There is no base url, just host and port. You could potentially do something with metadata, but you'd have to customize everywhere it is used